# Split dataframe into grouped chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split a dataframe into chunks. I have created a function which is able to split a dataframe into equal size chunks however am unable to figure out how to split by groups.

Each split of dataframe **must include all instances of a grouping variable**, I'd like flexibility on how many groups could be included (as they are relatively small).

Example dataframe:

```
A  1
A  2
B  3
C  1
D  9
D  10
```

Target splits (include at least two groups):

Split 1:

```
A  1
A  2
B  3
```

Split 2:

```
C  1
D  9
D  10
```

If helpful, my current function looks like the following:

```
def split_frame(sequence, size=10000):
    return (sequence[position:position + size] for position in range(0, len(sequence), size))
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to retain the order? Say you have 4 rows of A, then 9 rows of B, then 5 rows of C. Would you want the As be grouped with the Cs? Are all the instances of a grouping variable consecutive in the original dataframe?

Comment: Order doesn’t matter providing each split includes all elements of the group. Of course the groups will have varying lengths. The grouping variables are random number IDs in the data frame I intend to apply this to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works in Python 2 and 3:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'v', 'f'], columns=['A']) 

def iter_by_group(df, column, num_groups):
    groups = []
    for i, group in df.groupby(column):
        groups.append(group)
        if len(groups) == num_groups:
            yield pd.concat(groups)
            groups = []
    if groups:
        yield pd.concat(groups)

for group in iter_by_group(df, 'A', 2):
    print(group)

A
0  a
1  a
4  a
5  a
2  b
6  b

A
3  c
9  f

A
7  v
8  v
```

Comment: Did I get your question right? Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: I think so! Just testing that it retains the groups - each dataframe chunk must include every instance of the group (which is the important thing). I hope that was clear in the question. Thanks for help!

Comment: So after testing it, I don't think it is... I've run the following code:

    my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'v', 'f'], columns=['A'])

    def iter_dataframe(dataframe, chunk_size):
    for chunk_index, df_chunk in dataframe.groupby(np.arange(len(dataframe)) // chunk_size):
        yield chunk_index, df_chunk


    for group in iter_dataframe(my_df, 2):
        print(my_df)

It appears to split it into equal dataframes, but I need to split it into smaller chunks by group (I hope I'm being clear).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "split into smaller chunks by group"? Can you provide the expected output in this example?

Comment: Sure, so assume we want two groups per dataframe, I’d expect to have a dataframe with a, a, a, a, b, b - a dataframe with c, v, v and a dataframe with ‘f’ given the above example

Comment: Thanks Dennis. This looks right but i think the code you've pasted has a syntax error near the lambda function? EDIT: I'm using Python 3! Apologies! Is there a fix for the tuple unpacking near the lambda function? THANK YOU

Comment: I've found a simpler solution and updated the answer. Please try this one.

Comment: Genius! This works exactly as needed - thank you very much for your help and efforts!

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Dennis Golomazov was too slow for my dataframes.
Storing the groups in a list and returning them with pd.concat() is a performance killer.

Here is a slightly faster version.
It enumerates the groups and returns them via their group number.

```
import pandas as pd

def group_chunks(df, column, chunk_size):
    df["n_group"] = df.groupby(column).ngroup()
    lower_group_index = 0
    upper_group_index = chunk_size - 1
    max_group_index = df["n_group"].max()
    while lower_group_index <= max_group_index:
        yield df.loc[:, df.columns != "n_group"][
            df["n_group"].between(lower_group_index, upper_group_index)
        ]
        lower_group_index = upper_group_index + 1
        upper_group_index = upper_group_index + chunk_size

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'v', 'f'], columns=['A']) 
for chunk in group_chunks(df, 'A', 2):
    print(f"{chunk.sort_values(by='A')}\n")

   A
0  a
1  a
4  a
5  a
2  b
6  b

   A
3  c
9  f

   A
7  v
8  v
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
n = 2
splits = {g:df for g,df in df.groupby(df.groupby('A').ngroup().floordiv(n))}
```

Each `df` can be accessed by the key in the dictionary. It would also then be possible to concat them back to one `df`, which now shows the group in the index

```
pd.concat(splits,names = ['groups'])
```

Answer (score 0):

### A look at the various methods

```
def golomazov(df, column, num_groups):
    groups = []
    for i, group in df.groupby(column):
        groups.append(group)
        if len(groups) == num_groups:
            yield pd.concat(groups)
            groups = []
    if groups:
        yield pd.concat(groups)
        
def arigion(df, column, chunk_size):
    df["n_group"] = df.groupby(column).ngroup()
    lower_group_index = 0
    upper_group_index = chunk_size - 1
    max_group_index = df["n_group"].max()
    while lower_group_index <= max_group_index:
        yield df.loc[:, df.columns != "n_group"][
            df["n_group"].between(lower_group_index, upper_group_index)
        ]
        lower_group_index = upper_group_index + 1
        upper_group_index = upper_group_index + chunk_size

def rhug123(df, column, n):
    return {g: df for g, df in df.groupby(df.groupby('Symbol').ngroup().floordiv(n))}

def misantroop(df, column, num_groups):
    symbol_groups = df.groupby(column)
    groups = np.array_split(list(symbol_groups.groups), num_groups)
    for group in groups:
        yield pd.concat([symbol_groups.get_group(name) for name in group])

%timeit golomazov(df, 'Symbol', n)
157 ns ± 0.647 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
from pympler.asizeof = 414176

%timeit arigion(df, 'Symbol', n)
160 ns ± 0.903 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
from pympler.asizeof = 414176

%timeit rhug123(df, 'Symbol', n)
5.53 ms ± 28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
from pympler.asizeof = 57534096

%timeit misantroop(df, 'Symbol', num_groups=n*40)
191 ns ± 2.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
from pympler.asizeof = 414176
```