# Looping over a pandas Dataframe and returning multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

This is a question that builds on the question here: [Split dataframe into grouped chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411506/split-dataframe-into-grouped-chunks)

I have been trying to break a big dataset into different chunks and was using the solution proposed in the question above to do this. This is the code I'm referring to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'v', 'f'], columns=['A']) 

def iter_by_group(df, column, num_groups):
    groups = []
    for i, group in df.groupby(column):
    groups.append(group)
        if len(groups) == num_groups:
            yield pd.concat(groups)
            groups = []
    if groups:
        yield pd.concat(groups)

for group in iter_by_group(df, 'A', 2):
print(group)
```

The result of the print is:

```
    A
 0  a
 1  a
 4  a
 5  a
 2  b
 6  b
    A
 3  c
 9  f
    A
 7  v
 8  v
```

The issue is that I'm not managing to then go and call each of these chunks individually as if I just call group it returns me the last group only and if instead of print I use return in the last for loop it only gets me the first chunk. How could I alter the code so that I can call each of the chunks individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.factorize` to form groups, then store the grouped object in a dict. Here's it's based on the order of occurrence.  Add `sort=True` to `pd.factorize` to form groups based on the sorted key ordering

```
N = 2
col = 'A'

d = dict(tuple(df.groupby((pd.factorize(df[col])[0]+N)//N)))
```

#### Output:

```
d[1]
#   A
#0  a
#1  a
#2  b
#4  a
#5  a
#6  b

d[2]
#   A
#3  c
#9  f

d[3]
#   A
#7  v
#8  v
```